# Dict containing a list containing more dicts - Updating

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Below I have a simple program. What i intend to do is to merge the two dictionaries. But i don't want to copy any of the values in regards to offset, limit, results. Just the key labeled "Items" and the list under that, containing more dictionaries.

My problem is is that i can pull the list under, items and store it in a variable which removes the other keys, however when i go to add it to the other list, instead of updating, it replaces the values.

For instance i have two dictionaries:

```
my_dict: {'status': 'ok', 'result': {'items': [{'Test': 1000}, {'Test2': 2000}]}}
my_dict2: {'status': 'ok', 'result': {'items': [{'Test3': 1000}, {'Test4': 2000}]}}
```

My result i expect is:

```
my_dict2: {'status': 'ok', 'result': {'items': [{'Test3': 1000}, {'Test4': 2000}, {'Test': 1000}, {'Test2': 2000}]}}
```

But i get:

```
my_dict2: {'status': 'ok', 'result': {'items': [{'Test': 1000}, {'Test2': 2000}]}}
```

code:

```
my_dict = {
    "status": "ok",
    "result": {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 1000,
        "total": 839,
        "items": [
            {
}
]
}
}

my_dict2 = my_dict

my_dict.update({'result': {'items': [{'Test': 1000},{'Test2': 2000}]}})
my_dict_values = my_dict['result']['items']

my_dict2.update({'result': {'items': [{'Test3': 1000},{'Test4': 2000}]}})
print "Before: %s" % (my_dict2)
my_dict2.update({'result': {'items': my_dict_values}})
print "After: %s" % (my_dict2)
```

Comment: You are updating `my_dict2`, when you really just want to update `my_dict2['items']`.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh Thanks for editing my post. I forgot to add the code snip for the top ;-)

Comment: @Paul yes it seems that's exactly what i was doing, the accepting answer gives me the correct function to use. Thanks buddy. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems normal because dictionary update() method overrides values if given key exists in the dictionary.

`my_dict2` has key `'result'` which has a value `{'items': [{'Test3': 1000},{'Test4': 2000}]}`.

You're overriding the value of `'result'` with `my_dict_values` which is `{'items': [{'Test': 1000}, {'Test2': 2000}]}`

To get expected results, you might wanna try:

```
my_dict2['result']['items'].extend(my_dict_values)
```

Comment: ahh thank you! I knew it was just something simple i was doing wrong. I just misunderstood the update functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the 'result' value by using update, maybe changing the line

```
my_dict2.update({'result': {'items': my_dict_values}})
```

to

```
my_dict2['results']['items'] += my_dict_values
```

will do it for you